# Can Park Entrances be Changed?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

Can park entrances in RollerCoaster Tycoon 3 be changed, in sandbox mode or otherwise?

That is, can you change the physical model or position of the entrance gates?  I noticed that most (all?) of the career mode scenarios do this, and at least one of them actually has *two* active entrances on opposite ends of the park.

I couldn't find any park entrance objects to place as scenery, and it wouldn't let me delete the existing one because I "didn't own it."  Clicking the gate does nothing, and there's nothing in the park management screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's only possible to use custom park entrances in the map editor.  The career mode and sandbox mode both lock down anything outside the borders of the park, and that includes the park entrances.

The map editor gives you the option to place any of the 'themed' park entrances (you might even be able to have a park with no entrance set, but I'm not 100% sure).  You can also place (and thus, change) the location that peeps enter the map from, which lets you have an 'underground' entrance to a map (provided you have a fully patched version of the game)